# Only last item added to array

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code. It iterates through an array which contains two items in item["type] and two items in item["count(*)"]

However, when I add the items to the arrays, only the last ones are added. What am I doing wrong?

```
$behTypes = array();
$behValues = array();
foreach($behaviours as $item){
    $behTypes = $item["type"];
    $behValues = intval($item["count(*)"]);
}
echo($behTypes);
echo($behValues);
```

Comment: don't forget `[]`.  `$behTypes[] = $item["type"];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an element to an array in PHP, use the `[]` syntax on the array.  This syntax behaves identically with [**`array_push()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).  To quote the documentation...

> array_push() treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array. The length of array increases by the number of variables pushed. Has the same effect as:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $array[] = $var;
> ?>
> ```

Here is the fix applied to your code...

```
$behTypes = array();
$behValues = array();
foreach($behaviours as $item){
    $behTypes[] = $item["type"];
    $behValues[] = intval($item["count(*)"]);
}
echo($behTypes);
echo($behValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$behTypes = array();
$behValues = array();
foreach($behaviours as $item){
    $behTypes[] = $item["type"];
    $behValues[] = intval($item["count(*)"]);
}
echo($behTypes);
echo($behValues);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO!  Code-only answers are discouraged.  Also, I'm not sure that this answer offers anything that the comment on the question, or other answers, add?

Comment: Comment could have been posted around the same time, this answer was posted?  On new questions, there is a lot of overlap.  This answer is correct, and yes, so was your comment.

Answer (score 0):

you need to push items into array.

```
$behTypes = array();
$behValues = array();
foreach($behaviours as $item){
    array_push($behTypes, $item["type"]);
    array_push($behValues, intval($item["count(*)"]));
//OR
    //$behTypes[] = $item["type"];
  //  $behValues[] = intval($item["count(*)"]);
}
print_r($behTypes);
print_r($behValues);
```